# Cannot create directory in HDFS. Name node is in safe mode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, namenode, datanode

I'm have deployed Hadoop in docker which is running on aws ec2 ubuntu AMI instance.

when I try to create a directory in hdfs it says **Cannot create directory. Name node is in safe mode**

below are the properties in hdfs-site.xml

```
name: dfs.replication
value: 1

name: dfs.namenode.name.dir
value: /usr/local/hadoop/data
```

when I check the hdfs report, it gives the below output.

```
bash-4.1# hdfs dfsadmin -report
19/01/05 12:34:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Safe mode is ON
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 335872 (328 KB)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 335872 (328 KB)
DFS Used%: 100.00%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
```

below is some detail about namenode.

```
bash-4.1# hdfs dfs -df
19/01/05 12:37:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Filesystem                Size    Used  Available       Use%
hdfs://0cd4da30c603:9000     0  335872          0  Infinity%
```

if I set to leave safe mode, within secs it's going back to safe mode.

```
bash-4.1# hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
19/01/05 12:42:26 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Safe mode is OFF
bash-4.1# hdfs dfsadmin -safemode get  
19/01/05 12:42:36 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Safe mode is ON
```

below is my file system information

```
bash-4.1# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          25G  6.2G   19G  26% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1       25G  6.2G   19G  26% /data/lab
/dev/xvda1       25G  6.2G   19G  26% /etc/resolv.conf
/dev/xvda1       25G  6.2G   19G  26% /etc/hostname
/dev/xvda1       25G  6.2G   19G  26% /etc/hosts
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /proc/kcore
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /proc/keys
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /proc/timer_list
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /proc/sched_debug
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /sys/firmware
```

what I'm expecting is to create a directory in hdfs to perform a MapReduce operation

Comment: Why use Docker over EMR? Or Ec2 instead of EKS when using Docker?

Comment: Hint: `DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)` and `DFS Used%: 100.00%` are the issues... It's not clear how you mounted the volumes for the NameNode or DataNode